# adaptive Chained Payments failed code 520009 - account is restricted

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-adaptive-payments, chained-payments

I am trying to set up a chained payment (working perfectly for the sandbox environment), but am getting error 520009 (Account is restricted) for live .

First reply response form PayPal

```
Array

(

[responseEnvelope] => Array

(

[timestamp] => 2014-05-08T00:18:05.168-07:00

[ack] => Failure

[correlationId] => 16ead17a17432

[build] => 10680030

)



[error] => Array

(

[0] => Array

(

[errorId] => 520009

[domain] => PLATFORM

[subdomain] => Application

[severity] => Error

[category] => Application

[message] => Account XXXX@gmail.com is restricted

[parameter] => Array

(

[0] => XXXX@gmail.com

)



)



)
```

Second response form paypal for "SetPaymentOptions response" =

```
Array
( 
[responseEnvelope] => Array
( 
    [timestamp] => 2014-05-08T00:18:06.185-07:00
    [ack] => Failure
    [correlationId] => b569e8963ed54
    [build] => 10680030
)

[error] => Array    
(
    [0] => Array    
    (    
        [errorId] => 580022    
        [domain] => PLATFORM    
        [subdomain] => Application
        [severity] => Error
        [category] => Application
        [message] => Invalid request parameter: payKey with value 
        [parameter] => Array
        (
            [0] => payKey   
            [1] =>     
        )
    )
)
)
```

Comment: Please *please* format your code as code and not double spaced so it is readable! I haven't used Paypal but it *looks* to me like it is receiving no value for the payKey.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting an "Account Restricted" error in the live environment then your PayPal account is restricted. Visit the Resolution Center within your PayPal account to determine why. You may have to contact customer service to resolve.